# Keycloak crashes when trying to start up in a Kubernetes Pod using helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jboss, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

Trying to run Keycloak as a standalone pod in Kubernetes. I ran `helm create` and here's what my `values.yaml` and `service.yaml` look like:

`values.yaml`

```
service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 30010

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths: []
  tls: []

resources: {}

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

`service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "keycloak.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "keycloak.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    {{- include "keycloak.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

For this install I just want to use the H2 embedded database.

When I run `helm install keycloak . -f values.yaml` and check the pod logs - I see the following logs in RED:

```
00:10:09,549 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
00:10:09,560 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockService] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Database error during release lock: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@33fbc61f
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.commit(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1159)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.2//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockService.releaseLock(CustomLockService.java:241)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.2//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$releaseLock$3(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:136)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.2//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:654)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.2//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.releaseLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:131)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:140)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.2//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:228)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@12.0.2//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:115)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2815)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:371)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:283)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:93)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@33fbc61f
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:126)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.commit(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1157)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@33fbc61f
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.lock(WrappedConnection.java:176)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getAutoCommit(WrappedConnection.java:868)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:122)
    ... 46 more

00:10:09,563 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Error during startup: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1575)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.2//org.keycloak.models.jpa.MigrationModelAdapter.init(MigrationModelAdapter.java:58)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.2//org.keycloak.models.jpa.MigrationModelAdapter.<init>(MigrationModelAdapter.java:42)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.2//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProvider.getMigrationModel(JpaRealmProvider.java:79)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@12.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:145)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.2//org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:99)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:234)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:175)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:138)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.2//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:228)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@12.0.2//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:115)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2815)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:371)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:283)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:93)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:50)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2082)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1990)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2770)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2604)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2599)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:505)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1526)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1598)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1566)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@21.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:777)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
    ... 73 more
```

It seems like there's some issue with starting up it's own H2 db - it's unable to acquire database connection - what more can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which helm chart are you using.

i have used this : https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak#database-setup helm chart and by default it create the database setup however if you want to use the MySQL you can update your `values.yaml`

Here you test your Docker image with standalone config first

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
```

in `values.yaml` you can configure the Postgres option, if true it will get auto-installed or if already running a database you can simply update the environment vars.

```
postgresql:
  # Disable PostgreSQL dependency
  enabled: false

extraEnv: |
  - name: DB_VENDOR
    value: postgres
  - name: DB_ADDR
    value: mypostgres
  - name: DB_PORT
    value: "5432"
  - name: DB_DATABASE
    value: mydb
```

**Extra**

here sharing simple YAML file for reference if you don't want to use to the helm it's only for development purpose

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        #image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.0
        image: harshmanvar/keycloak-demo
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: POSTGRES
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: postgres
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: keycloak
        - name: DB_USER
          value: root
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT
          value : "80"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT
          value: "443"
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
          value : keycloak.example.com
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
```

Comment: I actually don't need the db setup - I'm using the embedded H2 db which is why I'm surprised at the db connection error